# Were can I find a simple CPU Design tutorial / book?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture

I basically want to know how to make(In hardware and in a simulator) a simple CPU. A book that covers low level stuff like, like logic gates, and more high level stuff like a complete CPU. Ive tried to find this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Computing-Systems-Building-Principles/dp/0262640686/ref=ed_oe_p](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262640686) but here in Argentina it costs double to use credit card online, and I don't want to use 60 dollars on a book, i looked for a PDF of it, and I didn't find anything. I also don't want a complex collage level 1000 page book, I'm only 14 years old. The "best" and clear information on how a computer works I found were in video tutorials on how to build a redstone computer in the video game Minecraft.

Comment: Here's the thing, those 1000 page college text books are the length they are for a reason. Designing a CPU is not exactly trivial. If you want to make a little 4 bit thing with a small instruction set, there are plenty of hobby projects to be found on the web.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.nand2tetris.org/

Comment: This book is great, but of course this is a very opinionated question. http://www.buthowdoitknow.com/ or right from amazon for $16 ($10 for Kindle) http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=but+how+do+it+know&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abut+how+do+it+know

Comment: MIT open courseware 6.004, details change depending on which lecturer's version from which year is up at any given time.

Answer (score 7):

There are no CPU design tutorials because those who design CPUs are generally far beyond being tutored. Tutorial text are at the far lower levels:

- gate design (from transistors)
- MSI* components design (= register, mux, demux, adder) from gates
- ROM and RAM design (from gates or MSI components)

When you have mastered theses levels to sufficient degree you can probably imagine how a CPU could work.

Those 1000 page books (The Patterson & Hennessy books are my favourite) explain how a modern CPU is built. You don't need that to make a basic CPU, there are plenty designs on the web that show an 8 or 16 bit CPU built from 74xxx level chips.

*MSI - medium-scale integration (vs small-scale integration being logic gates etc.)